# node.js bot framework universalbot beginDialogAction usage?

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, chatbot

Maybe I'm stupid, but I really don't understand how to read the [node.js version of Microsoft's bot framework sdk](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/modules/_botbuilder_d_.html). I'm trying to figure out how to use [beginDialogAction()](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.universalbot.html#begindialogaction) or [endConversationAction()](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.universalbot.html#endconversationaction) in a [ConsoleConnector bot](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.consoleconnector.html). The documentation says it registers an action when triggered but no mention of how to trigger it. I want to leverage the idea that it can add a dialog in the middle of callstack outside of the normal flow.

I'm sorry I can't provide code but I can give this...

```
var connector = new builder.ConsoleConnector().listen();
var connector = new builder.ConsoleConnector().listen();
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);

bot.dialog('/', [
    function( session ) {
        builder.Prompts.text(session, "blah blah blah?");
    },
    function( session, results ) {
        // ...

        session.beginDialog('/foo');
        session.endDialog();
    }
]);

bot.dialog('/foo', [
    function( session, args ) {
        // ...
    },
    function( session, results ) {
        // ...
        session.endDialog();
    }
]);

bot.use({ botbuilder: function( session, next ) {

    // CALL THE ACTION 'bar' HERE TO ADD '/help' to the callstack

    // ...
    next();
}});

bot.beginDialogAction('bar', '/help');

bot.dialog('/help', [
    function( session, args ) {
        // ...
    },
    function( session, results ) {
        // ...
        session.endDialog();
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the way I understand and use it: An action is something explicit that you can call from within your dialog flow to trigger other dialogs + parameters.

As an example here is a normal flow for your bot, triggered by dialog input:

```
bot.dialog('/', new builder.IntentDialog()
.matches(/^command1/i, '/command1')
.matches(/command2/i, '/command2')
.onDefault(..));

bot.dialog('/command1', [
    function (session) {
        session.send('Hello.');
    }
]);
```

For example you can use dialog actions to trigger an action directly instead of routing to a function:

```
    .onDefault(builder.DialogAction.send("Hello World!"))
```

As for beginDialogAction(), think of this as a cross between both. Consider this example of a card:

```
// An actions is just a normal card of any type that
// features a dialogAction with the respective parameters.
bot.dialog('/Action', [
    function (session) { 
        // Create a new message. Note that cards are managed as attachments
        // that each channel can interpret as they see fit. Remember that some
        // channels are text only, so they will have to adapt.
        var msg = new builder.Message(session)
            .textFormat(builder.TextFormat.xml)
            .attachments([
                // This is the actual hero card. For each card you can add the
                // specific options like title, text and so on.
                new builder.HeroCard(session)
                    .title("Hero Card")
                    .subtitle("Microsoft Bot Framework")
                    .text("Build and connect intelligent bots to interact with your users naturally wherever they are, from text/sms to Skype, Slack, Office 365 mail and other popular services.")
                    .images([
                        builder.CardImage.create(session, "https://bot-framework.azureedge.net/bot-icons-v1/bot-framework-default-7.png")
                    ])
                    .buttons([
                        builder.CardAction.dialogAction(session, "News", "https://blog.botframework.com/", "Get news")
                    ])
            ]);

        // Send the message to the user and end the dialog
        session.send(msg);
        session.endDialog();
    }
]);
```

Note that this card triggers an action called "News" with the parameter "https://blog.botframework.com/" via a button. Think of this as a function that is called within your dialog by pressing the button on the card. Now to define that function, we do:

```
// An action is essentially a card calling a global dialog method
// with respective parameters. So instead of using choice prompts
// or a similar waterfall approach, you can link to separate
// dialogs.
// The dialog action will route the action command to a dialog.
bot.beginDialogAction('News', '/News');

// Create the dialog itself.
bot.dialog('/News', [
    function (session, args) {
        session.endDialog("Loading news from: " + args.data);
    }
]);
```

So with this we can display generic news dialogs based on the parameter we hand over, triggered by other dialogs.

Makes sense?